# How do I get a channel push to receive a message on the server in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently learning the Phoenix Framework and I'm having a little trouble getting the handle_in method matching on my channel push.

My javascript (technically it's typescript) looks like this:

```
let channel = this.socket.chan('rooms:lobby', {});

channel.join().receive('ok', channel => {
  console.log(`Joined the channel`);
});

// channel.on("feed", payload => {
//   console.log(`Message from server: ${payload.list}`);
// });

channel.push("new:msg", 'test message');
```

And the server side def look like this:

```
def handle_in("new:msg", msg, socket) do
  IO.puts "Message from the client: #{msg}"

  {:noreply,socket  }
end
```

Does anyone have any idea why my channel push is not matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this out. It turns out that I was not initializing the socket properly in my javascript. Setting up the logger in the js was very helpful to find the issue:

```
this.socket.logger = (kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) };
this.socket.connect({ user_id: "123" })
```

Also thanks for letting me know that 16.0 was out :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the socket and channel logic set up on the server side? Also - what version of Phoenix are you using? In versions > 0.15.0  you should have something like this in `lib/app/endpoint.ex`

```
# lib/hello_phoenix/endpoint.ex
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint

  socket "/socket", HelloPhoenix.UserSocket
  ...
end
```

Then the socket module:

```
# web/channels/user_socket.ex
defmodule HelloPhoenix.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  channel "rooms:*", HelloPhoenix.RoomChannel
  ...
end
```

Then you should have a channel module that looks like:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.RoomChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("rooms:lobby", auth_msg, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def join("rooms:" <> _private_room_id, _auth_msg, socket) do
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_out("new_msg", payload, socket) do
    push socket, "new_msg", payload
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

You can read more about channels on the official guides: http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.16.0/docs/channels

Also in 0.16.0 in your JavaScript `socket.chan` was renamed to `socket.channel` You can read about this in the [Upgrade Guide](https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/969d75d1562979a3ae37)

Comment: I guess I should given more information like what version I was running :). I'm going to try upgrading to 16.0 first (I'm on 15.0).

Comment: My project checks out with all of points you brought up. I did upgrade to 16 and I still can't get the push to work. I'm able to connect fine, it's only the push call: channel.push("new:msg", 'test message'); That doesn't seem to be calling my serverside handle_in/3 method.

Comment: @Korbin Could you publish your repository somewhere?